# javascript object reference by array

Tags: javascript

How can I refer to an object element dynamically during a loop by using an array, something like this:

```
var obj = {};
var lvl = ['x','y','z'];
var ol = [];
for (var l in lvl){
    ol.push( lvl[l] )
    obj[ol] = 'someval'
}
```

so where the reference may be obj[x][y][z] so each time the loop iterates, an additional key reference is appended, but I do not know how many levels there will be.

Not sure if I have explained that very well ?!

Comment: are you sure you want this? `obj[ol]` this will keep an array as key of object. or do you want `obj[ol[l]]`.

Comment: I am looking to dynamically add [] each time the loop iterates, so at the end of this example the refernce would be obj[x][y][z].

Comment: Ok so just to be clear you want obj[x][y][z] = "someval".  Essentially nesting object keys?

Comment: yes, I am looping through an array and I need to be able to push to or add key-value pairs to a nested object

Comment: did any of the answers match what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you answered my comment I believe this code will provide the nested object structure you are looking for.

```
var obj = {};
var lvl = ['x','y','z'];
var ol = {};

for (var i = 0; i < lvl.length; i++){
  obj[i] = {};  
  ol = obj[key];
}
```

Comment: the `var key in lvl` bit is wrong because it would give you `0,1,2,length` not `x,y,z`. Found out the hard way when testing my own answer. Use foreach or a regular `for(x=0;x<lvl.length;x++)` loop.

Comment: Alternatively, you can change `lvl` to be `{x:'',y:'',z:''}` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want `someval` to be the value of `obj.x.y.z`? You can always refer to the newly created levels using a variable:

```
var obj = {};
var levels = ['x','y','z'];

var pointer = obj;

for (var l=0; l<levels.length; l++) {
    key = levels[l];

    if (l < levels.length-1) {   // if not last element
        pointer[key] = {};
        pointer = pointer[key];
    }
    else {                       // if last element
        pointer[key] = 'someval';
    }
}

console.log(obj); // should log {x:{y:{z:"someval"}}}
```

Comment: OK. Finally got it working. Remember, variables are references only when they're pointing to arrays or objects. But they're values once you assign a string or number to them.. arrrrgh...